# why does this return an empty data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

```
import pandas as pd, networkx as nx, numpy as np, pylab
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
connect = pd.DataFrame(data = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Network resources/693137576_T_ONTIME_REPORTING.csv'), columns = ['FL_DATE','ORIGIN','ORIGIN_CITY_NAME','ORIGIN_STATE_ABR','DEST','DEST_CITY_NAME','DEST_STATE_ABR','DISTANCE'])
G = nx.Graph()
connectdata = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['ORIGIN','ORIGIN_CITY_NAME','ORIGIN_ST','DEST','DEST_CITY_NAME','DEST_ST','DISTANCE'])
for i in range(0,607346):
  if G.has_edge(connect.iloc[i,1], connect.iloc[i,5]) == False:
    G.add_edge(connect.iloc[i,1], connect.iloc[i,5])
    connectdata.append({'ORIGIN': connect.iloc[i,1],'ORIGIN_CITY_NAME': connect.iloc[i,2],'ORIGIN_ST': connect.iloc[i,3],'DEST': connect.iloc[i,4],'DEST_CITY_NAME': connect.iloc[i,5],'DEST_ST': connect.iloc[i,6],'DISTANCE': connect.iloc[i,7],'NO_OF_FLIGHTS': 1 }, ignore_index = True)
print(G.number_of_nodes())
pd.set_option('display.max_columns',None)
print(connectdata)
```

Here I am simply importing a dataframe, creating a Graph and then a dataframe. The graph being formed is fine, but the data frame is empty, any reason why this is happening? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly when You get empty DataFrame in your output with only column names/header names it's because of irregular dimensions of your data or number of rows of each column does not match to show the output.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to :

```
connectdata = 
connectdata.append({'ORIGIN': connect.iloc[i,1],'ORIGIN_CITY_NAME': connect.iloc[i,2],'ORIGIN_ST': connect.iloc[i,3],'DEST': connect.iloc[i,4],'DEST_CITY_NAME': connect.iloc[i,5],'DEST_ST': connect.iloc[i,6],'DISTANCE': connect.iloc[i,7],'NO_OF_FLIGHTS': 1 }, ignore_index = True)
```